# How do I prevent users from adding new tables in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel file where clients are allowed to write in some columns. All other columns are not visible and blocked, so they won't write any more than is expected from them.

BUT, they create new table and write there their stuff. How can I block creating new tables?

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far?

Comment: I tried to block it with password, but it seems that this option is only for collumns or rows in one of the tables. And there is no solution for my problem in standard Excel options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into `Allow Users to Edit Ranges` on the `Review Tab` in the `Changes` section, you will find options there to only allow users to change certain ranges of cells.

[image]

As soon as this is turned on, they can not add tables. I tested it in Excel 2010. Not sure what version you have, but the same feature is available.

There are even features for you to set specific permissions for certain users if you choose.